# Duplicated requests in Postman are empty

Tags: postman

I have some valid requests on my Postman. After I choose one of the requests -> Duplicate -> a "duplicate" request is created. All additional headers are missing, request body is empty and also "pre-request script" is missing.

I'm using Postman Version 9.14.12, working on Windows 10.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting...

When you copy a request the data of the request body, the URL and all the other information is saved, but it's not presented.

You just need to change the name of the duplicate (rename) and then you will see everything.

Comment: I've just come across this issue too and your workaround does the job. Seems like it only started happening after the recent update as I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem. Turns out you have to make sure that you click `Save` for the original request you are trying to duplicate before you duplicate it.

[Duplicate Request’ not working](https://community.postman.com/t/duplicate-request-not-working/4255/5)

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be because you did not save the old request yet, just save it the duplicate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

In v10.19.10 saving the old request and duplicating the same keeps on loading. Until you close the app and reopen can show up the duplicated.

Comment: Did you find a solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Postman v10.16.3, There is a toggle button to AutoSave (Beta) requests and collections in settings.